# Tensorflow: tf.gradients between different paths of the graph

Tags: graph, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, gradient

I am working on a DDPG implementation, which requires the computation of one network's (below: `critic`) gradients with respect to another network's (below: `actor`) output. My code already makes use of queues instead of feed dicts for the most part, but I could not do so for this specific part yet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()

states = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,))
actions = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,))

actor = states * 1
critic = states * 1 + actions

grads_indirect = tf.gradients(critic, actions)
grads_direct = tf.gradients(critic, actor)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    act = sess.run(actor, {states: [1.]})
    print(act)  # -> [1.]
    cri = sess.run(critic, {states: [1.], actions: [2.]})
    print(cri)  # -> [3.]
    grad1 = sess.run(grads_indirect, {states: [1.], actions: act})
    print(grad1)  # -> [[1.]]
    grad2 = sess.run(grads_direct, {states: [1.], actions: [2.]})
    print(grad2)  # -> TypeError: Fetch argument has invalid type 'NoneType'
```

`grad1` here computes the gradients w.r.t. to the fed-in actions, which were previously computed by the `actor`. `grad2` should do the same, but directly inside of the graph without the need for feeding the actions back in but by evaluating `actor` directly. The problem is that `grads_direct` is `None`:

```
print(grads_direct)  # [None]
```

How can I achieve this? Is there a dedicated "evaluate this tensor" operation I could make use of? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you don't use `actor` to compute `critic` so the gradient is None.

You should do:

```
actor = states * 1
critic = actor + actions  # change here

grads_indirect = tf.gradients(critic, actions)
grads_direct = tf.gradients(critic, actor)
```